# Conda, Tensorflow, and Keras version mismatch issue

Tags: tensorflow, keras, anaconda, conda, keras-layer

**When I try to use Keras in my Conda environment I get this  error:**

```
pr_curve_pb = _pr_curve_summary.pb attributeerror: 'module' object has no attribute 'pb'
```

**Error traces:**

```
File "/anaconda3/envs/tensorflow/lib/python3.6/site-packages/keras/init.py", line 3, in 
from . import utils
File "/anaconda3/envs/tensorflow/lib/python3.6/site-packages/keras/utils/init.py", line 6, in 
from . import conv_utils
File "/anaconda3/envs/tensorflow/lib/python3.6/site-packages/keras/utils/conv_utils.py", line 9, in 
from .. import backend as K
File "/anaconda3/envs/tensorflow/lib/python3.6/site-packages/keras/backend/init.py", line 1, in 
from .load_backend import epsilon
File "/anaconda3/envs/tensorflow/lib/python3.6/site-packages/keras/backend/load_backend.py", line 90, in 
from .tensorflow_backend import *
File "/anaconda3/envs/tensorflow/lib/python3.6/site-packages/keras/backend/tensorflow_backend.py", line 5, in 
import tensorflow as tf
File "/anaconda3/envs/tensorflow/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow/init.py", line 98, in 
from tensorflow_core import *
File "/anaconda3/envs/tensorflow/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow_core/init.py", line 45, in 
from . _api.v2 import compat
File "/anaconda3/envs/tensorflow/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow_core/_api/v2/compat/init.py", line 24, in 
from . import v2
File "/anaconda3/envs/tensorflow/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow_core/_api/v2/compat/v2/init.py", line 32, in 
from . import compat
File "/anaconda3/envs/tensorflow/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow_core/_api/v2/compat/v2/compat/init.py", line 23, in 
from tensorflow._api.v2.compat import v1
File "/anaconda3/envs/tensorflow/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow_core/_api/v2/compat/init.py", line 24, in 
from . import v2
File "/anaconda3/envs/tensorflow/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorflow_core/_api/v2/compat/v2/init.py", line 314, in 
from tensorboard.summary._tf import summary
File "/anaconda3/envs/tensorflow/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorboard/summary/init.py", line 25, in 
from tensorboard.summary import v1
File "/anaconda3/envs/tensorflow/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tensorboard/summary/v1.py", line 46, in 
pr_curve_pb = _pr_curve_summary.pb
AttributeError: module 'tensorboard.plugins.pr_curve.summary' has no attribute 'pb'
```

I tried to uninstall and install again but did not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got a very similar error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/runner/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/__init__.py", line 99, in <module>
    from tensorflow_core import *
  File "/home/runner/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow_core/__init__.py", line 36, in <module>
    from tensorflow._api.v1 import compat
  File "/home/runner/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow_core/_api/v1/compat/__init__.py", line 24, in <module>
    from tensorflow._api.v1.compat import v2
  File "/home/runner/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow_core/_api/v1/compat/v2/__init__.py", line 322, in <module>
    from tensorboard.summary._tf import summary
  File "/home/runner/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorboard/summary/__init__.py", line 25, in <module>
    from tensorboard.summary import v1
  File "/home/runner/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorboard/summary/v1.py", line 46, in <module>
    pr_curve_pb = _pr_curve_summary.pb
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'pb'
```

This is with Python 2.7 and TF 1.15.0, within a [GitHub CI workflow](https://github.com/rwth-i6/returnn/runs/1436856728).

While searching for this exception, I found this post here, but also
[this](https://github.com/aqeelanwar/SocialDistancingAI/issues/3): `AttributeError: module 'tensorboard.plugins.pr_curve.summary' has no attribute 'pb'`

This links to [this comment](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorboard/issues/1862#issuecomment-521876133), which suggests to `pip uninstall tensorflow-tensorboard`, as there was the old package `tensorflow-tensorboard`, and the new package `tensorboard`, and that might mess it up.

In my case, this did not help (I got an exception that `tensorflow-tensorboard` is not installed, but neither was `tensorboard`), although the package `tensorboard` existed in `~/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages`.

The solution, which worked for me, was simply:

```
rm -rf ~/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorboard*
```

And then followed by a new installation of TF (`pip install --user tensorflow==1.15.0`).

Answer (score 1):

**I found a solution:**

**Try to install theses packages with Conda Run**

```
    conda install -c anaconda tensorflow-gpu 
    
    conda install -c anaconda keras
```

Answer (score 1):

I got the error mentioned above when trying to import `kerastuner` (which also imports `tensorflow`) after a recent `conda update --all` (conda would not allow me to install `keras-tuner` until I updated all packages).  Got [this](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/37525#issuecomment-685954178) great advice from github and it solved my problem:

```
conda remove tensorflow
conda install tensorflow-estimator=2.1
conda install tensorflow-gpu=2.1
```

If you installed `kerastuner before doing the above, it will no longer be installed.  So you will need to follow the [instructions][2] to install` kerastuner` again (one of the recommended methods is currently as follows):